# multidimensional array delete repetition - matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, intersection

I have a multidimensional array A(:,:,i) for i=1:n and A is of size 6x6

I set the sub-matrices A(1:2,1:2,i)=0 and A(3:6,3:6,i)=0.

I get a series of matrices (exactly n matrices) but now there are many repetitions for example for i=1:8 I have exactly the same matrix.

Is there a way to keep only the matrices which are different and delete the repetitions?

I would like to have like the function "intersect" but for the matrices.

Example : if A(:,:,1)==A(:,:,3) then I would like to delete A(:,:,3) and only keep in my list of A matrices A(:,:,1).

Thank you.

Comment: I have problems to understand your question. Isn't A of size [6 6 n]? Let's say you have A(:,:,1) and A(:,:,3) which are equal, then you want to remove one of the two slices?

Comment: yes. I get "n" times matrices A of size 6 x 6 and for example A(:,:,1)==A(:,:,3) . I would like to delete A(:,:,3) and keep only A(:,:,1). Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the `unique` function but it only supports rows in a 2D matrix, not 2D matrix in a 3D matrix. To solve this, convert your 3D matrix into a 2D matrix where each slice `A(:,:,i)` becomes a row `B(i,:)`. Then apply unique and revert the conversion back to 3D.

```
zs=size(A);
B=reshape(A,[],sz(3)).';
reshape(unique(B,'rows').',sz(1),sz(2),[]);
```